# How do you reflect a list in Java?

Tags: java, list, reflection, field, instance

I want to reflect a private list in Java, add some elements to an instance of it, and set the original list to the instance. How can I do this? I tried the using fields, but Java is unable to cast a Field to a List.

Comment: You have a field of type `List`? you want to retrieve the referenced `List` object and add something to it?

Comment: Seems like an XY problem. Why do you want to do that? If the list is private maybe there's a reason...

Comment: The list contains textures for a game (Minecraft). The Minecraft Forge developers told me that to add textures from an external source I should reflect this list and add to it.

Comment: I expect the devs to be smarter than that. Isn't there a method to add a new texture in this list? Using reflection for this seems like an ugly hack...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Field.get` and `Field.set`.

```
Field field = Foo.class.getField("fieldName");
List<Bar> list = (List<Bar>) field.get(myFoo);
List<Bar> changedList = changeList(list);
field.set(myFoo, changedList);
```

Comment: I'm probably going to look like an idiot for asking this, but what should myFoo be? I tried instancing a list as an arraylist, but it gives me java.lang.IllegalArgumentException